# Invariant Violation: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path when updating json array items in redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

This question might have been asked multiple times but for me the behavior is unpredictable.
I am creating a cart using redux and when updating (increasing/decreasing) quantity, I get this warning.
Why I said unpredictable because sometimes I got this warning, sometimes not and because of this the below code written after this call works or not.[image]

And I make sure that I am not mutating the state. I have seen many examples/tutorials but nothing helps.
Any type of help is appreciated.
Code below

***userActions.js***

```
export function updateQuantity(productId, productQuantity) {
  return {
    type: type.UPDATE_QUANTITY,
    productId,
    productQuantity
  }
}
```

***ActionTypes.js***

```
export const UPDATE_QUANTITY = "UPDATE_QUANTITY";
```

***cartReducer.js***

```
case type.UPDATE_QUANTITY:
      return {
        ...state,
        storageItems: state.storageItems.map(
          (value,index) => 
          value.prodid === action.productId ? {...value, quantity: action.productQuantity} : value),
      }
```

Json example (for which I am trying to update quantity)

```
{
dis: 15
mrp: 320
packing: "10 kg"
prodid: 1
prodname: "ABC"
quantity: 1
rate: 260
total: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that "a mutation was detected **between dispatches**".  In other words, the problem is *not* in your reducer logic - it's in some other part of the application code.

You should look at any of your code that accesses `state.user.storageItems` to see if you're mutating the data there.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I just want to add that I am using this storageItems json array to display items in the screen. Something like (this.props.user.storageItems.map()..... returning the UI). Does that mutating the array?